# How to read a file extension from a variable in Bash?

Tags: android, bash

I am working on a major update for my Android utility that you flash in recovery and it uses Bash Scripting... Problem is, I kinda know nothing about bash!

Right now, I have two files... A `common` file that contains the variables and a `script` file that actually holds the file lists.

Here is the problem part of the `common` script:

```
 if [ ${android_version} == 5.* ]; then
    rm -rf /system/$file_name;
    else
        if [ -e ${file_name}.* ]; then
            rm -rf /system/$file_name;
        else
            rm -f /system/$file_name.apk;
        fi;
    fi;
```

And here's an example of where the `$file_name`'s come from:

```
# AOSP
aosp_remove_list="BootAnimation
Browser
...";

BootAnimation_list="media/bootanimation.zip";

Browser_list="app/Browser
app/ChromeBookmarksSyncAdapter";
```

So in the `common` file, it looks to see if it is Lollipop. If not, (this is the issue) it is supposed to look at the file name from the individual app lists and see if it contains a file extension. If it doesn't then it will remove the `$file_name` + `.apk`.

So in the above example, Browser's files get `.apk` added and removed from the system but the bootanimation `.zip` doesn't get removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe use suffix truncation to perform this.

With `${your_var_name%.zip}` you'll get ride of everything after the `.zip` including the zip, if present of course.

You can try this in your terminal:

```
a="toto.zip"
echo ${a%.zip}  #= > toto
```

You'll get more details about the possibilities here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html